# JPA Criteria API - Setup Joins and Fetch data from Joined Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have two entities `Foo` and `FooDerivedData`, described below.

Entity Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {

// skipping property declarations

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
public getFooDerivedData() {
    return fooDerivedData;
}
```

Entity FooDerivedData

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO_DERIVED_VW")
@Immutable
public class FooDerivedData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FOO_ID")
    long fooId;

    @Column(name = "FOO_COUNT")
    private Integer fooCount;

    @Column(name = "FOO_SUM")
    private BigDecimal fooSum;


    // Getters left out here
```

I am working with the JPA Criteria API (Hibernate is the JPA implementation) and I need the instance of the `FooDerivedData` to be loaded in `Foo`.  This is fetched eagerly by default, but I want it fetched using an inner join, not a separate select statement for every instance of `FooDerivedData`.  I was successfully able to add the inner join against `FooDerivedData`.

```
CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
root.join("fooDerivedData");
Predicate p = getPredicate(); // details omitted here
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(p);
```

Although I can see from the SQL in the logs that the inner join was added for FOO_DERIVED_VW, none of the columns are selected.  For every instance of `Foo`, I still need to have a separate select statement to get the data I have readily available.

Currently the query is something like this:

```
select f.foo_id, f.foo_bar from from FOO f
inner join FOO_DERIVED_VW d on d.foo_id = f.foo_id;
select d.foo_id, d.foo_count, d.foo_sum from FOO_DERIVED_VW d where foo_id = ?;
select d.foo_id, d.foo_count, d.foo_sum from FOO_DERIVED_VW d where foo_id = ?;
```

Note that I am not selecting any data from the joined FOO_DERIVED_VW and this data is being fulfilled by additional database hits.  I want the query to be like this:

```
select f.foo_id, f.foo_bar, d.foo_count, d.foo_sum from from FOO f
inner join FOO_DERIVED_VW d on d.foo_id = f.foo_id;
```

**How do I select the properties from a joined entity in the Criteria API?  Can I instruct javax.persistence.criteria.Root to select the attributes I am joining?**

I have attempted changing from a join to a fetch, or a fetch where I specified the join type.  In either case, it's failing with a Hibernate QueryException.

```
Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
root.fetch("fooDerivedData");
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join
>   fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in
>   the select list

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a couple of options here.  If your where conditions do not use any columns from the joined tables, then the fetch you tried should work as follows:

```
CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
root.fetch("fooDerivedData");
Predicate p = getPredicate(); // details omitted here
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(p);
```

If your predicate does include columns from joined tables then you can join as you have done (fetch won't work for this currently) and then also specify a dynamic entity graph (starting with JPA 2.1) by adding it to what you had:

```
CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
root.join("fooDerivedData");
Predicate p = getPredicate(); // details omitted here
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(p);
EntityGraph<Foo> fetchGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Foo.class);
fetchGraph.addSubgraph("fooDerivedData");
EntityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", fetchGraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to specify `FetchMode` for `getFooDerivedData()` as the default fetch type for OneToOne relationship is `EAGER`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Fetching the data eagerly is not the issue.  Fetching it efficiently is what I am after.  As it stands, there is no benefit to joining on FooDerivedData because I don't grab the data there.

Comment: If you are worried about performance and fetch graph of your entity then mark FooDerivedData as FETCH=LAZY. You can use any of the following options to avoiding any lazy initialization exceptions for FooDerivedData.  1. Remove getter method - in this option you will need to add FooDerivedData as a field in entity class. Remove getter method and provide a service method to fetch FooDerivedData. 2. JPA fetch graph - If you are using JPA 2.1 + version then look into providing fetch graph for your entity. 3. FETCH JOIN in jpql/HQL/Criteria - self explanatory. I would prefer option 1 as its safer!!

Comment: Sorry mate not enough characters for comments so here it goes part 2 of my comment. If the fetch mode is EAGER then hibernate will always query for associated entities whether you use it or not. You can check this out by enabling hibernate.show_sql property. If you are really worried about performance then please do consider one of the above options.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with core fetching strategies & how the Lazy fetching strategy can be used to improve performance.  My question was asked in what would be the context of option #3 in your comment, using a fetch join in the CriteriaQuery.  Based on my review of the raw SQL, I am not getting FooDerivedData via a join, I am getting it from separate select statements.  The raw SQL shows that I was able to add an inner join, but I just am not selecting the columns that I need.  I just want to tweak my usage of the CriteriaQuery to actually select data from the table/view that I am joining on.

Comment: So coming back to original problem, According to the Hibernate docs "a "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects". 

That is of course not possible, since "foodDeliveredData" isn't one of the selected fields, so the exception is completely right.  Please go to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html and search for the text I have quoted. In your case the easiest solution is to remove fetch join from criteria query and keep OneToOne relationship as EAGER.

Comment: Suken, I really appreciate your time going back and forth with me on this, but I still feel like we are dancing around what the primary issue is to me.  You explain the Exception, but that is a byproduct of not having fooDerivedData as one of the selected fields.  I want to make fooDerivedData one of the selected fields.  If you can explain how to make fooDerivedData one of the  selected fields of my CriteriaQuery, then I will happily accept/upvote your answer.  I am not 100% sure this is possible, but it would be silly to allow a join, but then to not provide a way to select the joined fields